# I can't decode an AES message in Dart (encrypted using CryptoJS)

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, cryptojs

I'm having trouble while trying to decode a message that was encrypted using CryptoJS on the web.
The functions used to encrypt and decrypt messages are:

```
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text,key).toString();
const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

On the web I can encrypt and decrypt without trouble, but when I tried to implement the decrypting andencrypting on a Flutter app it didn't work.

It would be great if there is a function written in dart that takes a base64 input as a String and a password also as a String to decrypt/encrypt the message.

I read about one but it does not work because it contains errors: [decrypt AES input on Flutter, when on web use cryptoJS AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864320/decrypt-aes-input-on-flutter-when-on-web-use-cryptojs-aes)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you found any solution, plz share